# How to prevent objects from automatically loading when I open Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Everytime I open Rstudio I find some variables in my environment. How can I remove these once for all?

Currently, whenever I open Rstudio I run `rm(list=ls())` to clear the environment first and then I run the necessary scripts.

I even tried to clear the environment before closing the Rstudio, but again in the next start I find the variables there.

Comment: remove a file `.Rhistory` or sth like that from your hard drive

Comment: do you save the workspace when you close rstudio? You want to save it after all the variables have been removed.

Comment: Tools -> Global options -> Restore .RData into workspace at startup ?

Comment: I use `file.remove(".RData")` and then use `q("no")` when closing R.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Tools -> Global options -> Restore .RData into workspace at startup (?)

Answer (score 5):

If you have already made the mistake of not changing the `Restore .RData into workspace at startup` setting in `Global options`, then to start a fresh R session by canceling the session reload on Rstudio, do this

- Go to `~/.rstudio/sessions/active`
- Remove all the active sessions `rm session-4ed31304 -R`

This solution works for `Ubuntu`. I guess the same steps can be followed for other operating systems. The only change should be in the directory where active R sessions are stored.

Comment: For windows, `%localappdata%\RStudio-Desktop`.  See https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State

Comment: This is now found in `~/.local/share/rstudio/sessions/active` on Ubuntu.