# How do I start R without reloading the workspace?

Tags: r

Please let me know how to start R without reloading the workspace (previous rda file).

Thanks.

Ward

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent objects from automatically loading when I open Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074305/how-to-prevent-objects-from-automatically-loading-when-i-open-rstudio)

Comment: There's a setting in the preferences of whatever editor you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You can start R in a console writing

```
R --no-restore
```

That wouldn't restore anything. If you only need to avoid restoring the objects you have saved in that workspace, you can type

```
R --no-restore-data
```