# R is completely messed up after trying to download caret package

Tags: r, installation, package, caret

I tried to download the caret package in R and it started removing some packages I had and now I get these messages on R startup:

```
Warning: namespace ‘ggplot2’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘belPlotTest’
Warning: namespace ‘scales’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘belPlotTest’
Warning: namespace ‘cowplot’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘g’
Warning: namespace ‘forecast’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘mtgomeryPlot’
```

I tried `rm(belPlotTest)`, `rm(g)` and `rm(mtgomeryPlot)` and restarted R as recommended but I keep getting these messages. I have no idea what these messages mean. I have the latest R version from 2022, 4.1.2. please help :(

Comment: You need to show us all of your code, not just the error messages.

Comment: Have you tried `remove.packages("caret")` and/or `install.packages(c("ggplot2", "cowplot", <etc…>))`?

Comment: @dcarlson the error code are upon starting R, there is no code. I am trying reinstalling ggplot2 but I have to restart the console. I'm currently waiting on it to reload.

Comment: I now get
> library(ggplot2)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.1 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required

Comment: Sounds like you've got a mess on your hands that will take a while to sort out. You could probably fix it if you invest enough time (I find doing everything from a terminal rather than an IDE often avoids these kinds of errors - run as Administrator if on Windows). However unless you need this R version, why not use the fact you're going to have sink some time here as an opportunity to upgrade to 4.2.2 and reinstall the required packages?

Comment: I think you have (at least) two package libraries on your system, the system one and a user one.  You probably don't have permissions to modify the system one, so now you can get two versions of each package.  Find and delete the user library, then run R as an admin to install the packages you need.  Alternatively, delete everything except base packages from the system one, and install all contributed packages into your user lib.

Comment: alright it seems to have worked after restarting windows... weird

Answer (score 1):

I run into this error when I was updating packages, and incidentally hit "save workspace? yes" in `.RData`. Then it was everytime first loading all of the objects, and improper packages.

You can prevent this happening by chaning settings in RStudio. Try not to allow:

---

Tools -> Global options -> Restore .RData into workspace at startup (?)

---

See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074305/how-to-prevent-objects-from-automatically-loading-when-i-open-rstudio)